# Navigating file directories in remote servers using vim

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm new to vim and I'm trying it out to use it as my default editor and my C/C++ IDE. I always find myself having to edit files on a remote system. So I ssh into the remote system and edit my files. But all the configurations for my vim are on my local machine. So I tried vi scp://remoteserver//path_to_the file. But it only opens that one file. What if I want to edit another file in the server which is in the same directory. Is there a way to navigate the files in the directory of the remote server on my local machine using a plugin? Something like NERDTree

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to navigate the files in the directory of the remote server on my local machine using a plugin?

You only need to give Vim the path of a directory, with a trailing slash:

```
$ vim scp://remoteserver//path/to/the/
```

See `:help netrw`.